# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'socket' before initialization only on electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to set up an electron app where i send a message to the server, and the server puts the value on the readonly textarea.
But, when i start the app, i see this in the devtoools console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'socket' before initialization

But, when i open my browser (outside the electron app), it works as i wanted

why my code works as planned on my browser, but not on my electron?

```js
//SERVER HOSTING SECTION
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
const serverapp = express()
const server = http.createServer(serverapp)
let mensagem

serverapp.use(express.static(__dirname+'/data'))
const io = socketIo.listen(server);

server.listen(8889, ()=>console.log("adm online na porta http://localhost:7000"))

serverapp.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html"));

})

io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  console.log("nova conexao")
  socket.on('mensagem',(mensagem)=>{
    console.log("mensagem aqui:", mensagem)
    
    io.emit('resposta',mensagem)
  })
});



//ELECTRON APP SECTION
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  
  mainWindow.loadFile('data/index.html')
  //mainWindow.loadURL("http://localhost:7000/index.html");

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}


app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {

    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})




/*
$.getScript("server.js",function(){
  console.log("a")
})

*/
```

```html
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>aaaaaaaaaa</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="textbox" value="aba">
        <button onclick ="adicionar()"type="button" id="botao" for="textbox">Enviar</button>
        <button onclick ="enviar()"type="button" id="botao2" >Teste</button>
    </div>
 
     <textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
     
    <script src="codigo.js"></script> 
    
    
  </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
// code that sends and receives the message
let botaoAdicionar=document.querySelector("#botao")
let textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox')
let textarea = document.querySelector("#textarea")
let valortextbox;
console.log(valortextbox)
const socket = io.connect()

function adicionar(){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(textbox.value)
    textarea.value+=textbox.value
};


socket.on('resposta',(mensagem)=>{
    textarea.textContent+=mensagem
    console.log('resposta recebida')
})

function enviar(){
    let valortextbox= textbox.value
    socket.emit('mensagem', valortextbox)
    console.log("a")
}

/*
let testbtn=document.querySelector("#botao2")
testbtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("a")  
})

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i just needed to add "nodeIntegration: true" on browser window

const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 800,
height: 600,
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
contextIsolation: false,
preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
}
})